# How to prevent resource is not available error when deploying to war?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app. I have deployed it to .jar and everything works perfectly.

I have tried deploying it to .war that I place in webapps in Tomcat. My app has a login page, an index page, and one other page on /patchdetails.

I have a MVC controller that returns that page:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/patchdetails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public String patchDetail() {
    return "patchDetails";
}
```

The page is located on src/main/resources/templates/patchDetails.html.

When I try to access this page the server(Tomcat) shows the 404 error page.

Can anybody explain why deploying to jar works but deploying to war doesn't?

Comment: Did you configure (or let Spring Boot configure) a template engine?

Comment: I tried both, configuring one myself, and letting spring take charge, same result, jar works, war doesn't

Comment: Did you try putting these static resources under `src/main/resources/static`?

Comment: this doesn't work as I am returning the page as a template, if I put it in static I get the whitelabel page with an error

Comment: Did you configure your application to extend SpringBootServletInitializer  (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html)?

Comment: Yes I did, I have done all the steps there